# Did Draco Malfoy sexually assault Hermione Granger?

Tags: harry-potter

I've been lead to believe that there is a scene in either the book or the movie where Hermione is raped/sexually assaulted by Malfoy, did this actually happen?

Edit: while the OP has not provided us with any info, reading this question I could see how a reader might be confused when thinking about the scene where Bellatrix and Fenrir Greyback torture Hermione in Malfoy Mannor. The movie version is exceptionally creepy with Bellatrix biting Hermione.

Comment: not to go all skeptics.se on you but... "someone said" is a very broad claim and not much to go on. Is there something that you read/saw _in one of the works_ that leads you to believe this? Otherwise this is just unanswerable speculation...

Comment: Would they really have sex with a muggle born?

Comment: There was that one fanfic where Voldie won, and Hermione was to Death Eaters what Leia was to Jabba (without the PG13 rating), but Draco was actually a (kinda) good guy there

Comment: Having read all 7 books and watched all 8 movies, I can tell you there are definitely NO sexual scenes, implicit OR explicit, in any of them. There is torture, there is is murder, there is racism against various species, there's a bit of gore even, but there are are no sexytimes and very little cursing. JK Rowling is very particular in what she deems appropriate for Children's / YA fiction.

Comment: As loath as I am to cite _Cursed Child_, there are scenes where Draco and Hermione interact as adults and there's nothing in their interactions that would suggest she had ever been raped by him. As fanfic-like as that play was, I'm sure they would've brought it up if it was meant to have happened.

Comment: Reopened following [this meta discussion](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11728/31394).

Comment: @Gallifreyan You are making me more curious than I should be with that remark. Don't make me open a story identification question here...

Answer (score 19):

There is no evidence in the books or the movies that Hermione was raped by Draco. Or, as pointed out by ibid, "in any of Rowling's other writings/interviews".

Comment: Or in any of Rowling's other writings/interviews.

Comment: I feel like it's possible there are some interactions that could be considered sexual assault, if you were to squint, but I can't remember and I *really* don't want to google it

Comment: @JasonBaker - By Draco vis-a-vis Hermione?

Comment: The most likely time would be when Hermione was tortured by Belliatrix at Malfoy Manor, her and Luna. That said, there's no evidence that they went there.

Comment: And that would still be Bellatrix, anyway, not Draco.

Comment: @Adamant Or his cronies, but basically yes; there are definitely some unsettling implications involving other characters

Comment: @JasonBaker - I do not recall Malfoy ever even touching Hermione, or perhaps even casting a spell at her. He insulted her and used a whole lot of slurs, though.

Comment: malfoy was at the mansion, while fenris was clearly trying to get her to "eat" in more ways then one. so some speculation of eventual sexual misdeeds are fair .

Answer (score 13):

**No.**

When would he have had opportunity? In Malfoy Manor (book 7)? At the same time he is horribly conflicted and is willing to betray Voldemort by not revealing Harry Potter?

The whole pure-blood mania about the contamination of mud-bloods and not having any contact with them would also preclude this. *There has been some discussion that rape is a form of subjugation for undesirables. In this case I would think they would view any contact with a mud-blood as making themselves unclean.*

And there is nothing written or otherwise to support, with the exception of unsubstantiated speculation.